# Assert that the value literals have no type is false?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, c-preprocessor, literals

I've read in topics, articles and SO answers that the `#define` values have no type, I've made up my mind around this concept, thinking that the type is a property of the container variable, not a property of the value itself:

```
const char cVALUE = 100;    // 'cVALUE' is char with value 100, wich type is '100'?
const short sVALUE = 100;   // 'sVALUE' is short with value 100, wich type is '100'?
const int iVALUE = 100;     // 'iVALUE' is int with value 100, wich type is '100'?
#define VALUE 100           // wich type is 'VALUE'?
```

But, what about the [value suffixes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)?

```
#define VALUE_L   100l   // 'VALUE_L' is long?
#define VALUE_UL  100ul  // 'VALUE_UL' is unsigned long?
#define VALUE_LL  100ll  // 'VALUE_LL' is long long?
#define VALUE_ULL 100ull // 'VALUE_ULL' is unsigned long long?
```

In the code above, the type seems attached to the value, so all this raw values ​​are typed values, as opposed to what I've read before. But there's more! text literals even have qualifiers, for example:

```
#define TEXT "Text" // '"Text"' is an array of some kind of chars.
```

The text value in the `#define` above has type (a character type, if you're working with MSVC I think that the character type could vary changing the [project settings -> Character set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x480de8(v=vs.90).aspx), no idea if it is possible in another IDEs) it also has the `const` cualifier and it is a LValue instead of an RValue, all this behaviour differences between numeric and text literals disturbs me.

So, assuming that the character type is `char`, the type of the literal `"Text"` is `const char *`, `const char * const` or `const char[5]`? or at least, it doesn't have type at all before the correct type is deduced on the context?

And, in the C++11 standard, the text literals can also have type using some [prefixes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) that sets the charset:

```
#define TEXT   L"Text"  // wide string with char type wchar_t
#define TEXTu8 u8"Text" // UTF-8 string with char type char
#define TEXTu  u"Text"  // UTF-16 string with char type char16_t
#define TEXTU  U"Text"  // UTF-32 string with char type char32_t
```

After thinking about all this stuff, I'm pretty confused, so I'm begging for some advice:

- Why is common knowledge that the literal values (and `#define`s) have no type but a type can be specified with the literal? in other words: Assert that the value literals have no type is false?
- A value literal **without suffix** and no decimals (like `100`), can always be considered of type int?
- Which is the type and qualifiers of the text literals, even considering its prefixes?

Comment: The problem is in your premise. You group `#define`'s with values, but they are no such thing. They are macros. `VALUE` has no type in C++. `100` has the type `int`.

Comment: Also consider macro's like `#define FOO 0f,0U`. Assuming that macro's had a type (one type), then what type would that be?

Comment: @MSalters depends of the behaviour of the comma operator and the placement of `FOO`: `unsigned int a = FOO;` and `void f(float f, unsigned int i); f(FOO)` would make different behaviour.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster: Indeed, which is another reason why you can't talk about _the_ type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is common knowledge that the literal values (and #defines) have no type but a type can be specified with the literal? in other words: Assert that the value literals have no type is false?

It's not. Literals all have types, as specified in section 2.14 of the C++11 standard. Preprocessor macros are replaced before literals are interpreted.

> A value literal without suffix and no decimals (like 100), can always be considered of type int?

No; a decimal literal is the first of `int`, `long int` or `long long int` that can represent the value. Octal or hex literals may also be unsigned if necessary. Before 2011, `long long` wasn't considered, since it wasn't a standard type.

So `100` will have type `int` since it is small enough to be representable by `int`.

> Which is the type and qualifiers of the text literals, even considering its prefixes?

With no prefix, it's an array of `const char`, large enough to hold all the characters and the zero terminator. So `"Text"` has type `char const[5]`.

With prefixes, the character type changes to the types you give in the question; the array size is still large enough for all characters including the terminator.

Comment: Almost all answers helped me out to clarify my understanding of `#define`s and literal values, but this one focus on the questions I've made.

Answer (score 4):

In C and C++ the preprocessor and the compiler are two separate entities.

The preprocessor that handles `#define`s and other preprocessor directives has no type system. It manipulates strings of characters. And whatever values these characters represent is left to the compiler itself.

Consider

```
#define Y x[
```

This is a legal preprocessor directive, even though the string `x[` has no meaning in C. Yet you could use it as

```
char Y 10];
```

to declare and array `x` of `char`.

In fact C preprocessor can be used on source files for languages other than C. For instance, it is often used for FORTRAN sources. Since FORTRAN does not have a standard preprocessor.

Comment: So, a `#define` value have no type but a literal value does?

Comment: #define ONLY defines a textual replacement. It is the same as if you hit the keycombination for "replace something with someother" in your editor - but it also allows for arguemnts and some other "clever" stuff.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Sometimes the use of literal values in C can be ambigous. For instance, with function overloading you can have different calls for `foo(1)` and `foo(1.0)` or `foo(1l)`. For such cases the suffixes help to resolve ambiguity. But suffixes cannot substitute the full language typesystem.

Answer (score 2):

First, your questions:

> Assert that the value literals have no type is false?

Yes.

> A value literal without suffix and no decimals (like 100), can always be considered of type int?

I think by default, you get type `int`.

> Wich is the type and cualifiers of the text literals, even considering its prefixes?

If I remember correctly the default type is `char []`.

Second, some context:

Value literals *have* a type - it's just that it is not explicitly specified and not all types can be specified that way.

By declaring a constant you can specify the type explicitly and give the compiler a lot more information.

Consider that:

```
#define VALUE1 102
```

will tell you that your value is an int literal.

By declaring a const, you can say:

```
static const int VALUE1 = 102;
static const float VALUE1  = 102;
static const double VALUE1 = 102;
static const unsigned int VALUE1 = 102;
```

The correct/better way to do the `define` (correct is a relative term for using `define` for constants) would be:

```
#define VALUE1 (int(102))
#define VALUE1 (float(102))
// etc ...
```

At this point, you're better off adding constants.

Comment: `static const int Value1 = 102` and `#define VALUE2 102` give the compiler exactly the same type information. In each case, the named value is an int. Similarly for `102.0f` (float), `102.0` (double), and so on. There is rarely a need to use a cast to specify the type of a literal.

Comment: @PeteBecker, even if they give the same information, there are still problems, because you _expect_ to be able to treat it as a variable. For example, you can track the value of a constant in a debugger, but not a literal. With a literal (`define`), you see the defined tag in the source code, but the debugger doesn't understand to track that (because the information on the label is removed by the pre-compiler, before the compiler gets to it).

Comment: " you can track the value of a constant in a debugger, but not a literal" - true, but that's a tool limitation, not a language rule.

Answer (score 2):

They are correct, in that the preprocessor does not have types. Your example of

```
#define VALUE_L   100l
```

This does not mean that `VALUE_L` has type `long`. You can use the preprocessor to insert that text in the middle of a string literal- for example, [this](http://ideone.com/4L6b2x).

A macro does not have a type. The preprocessor can create tokens that the compiler may then interpret as having a type- but this is tangental and it does not have to do any such thing.

Also, `L""` literals are C++03 and `wchar_t`. A literal `""` has type `const char[1]`, and is an lvalue. The reason they are lvalues is because traditionally, they are pointed to with a `const char*`, and that pointer must point to an lvalue, else it would become invalid before being useful, and traditional C arrays cannot be rvalues.

Comment: "_You can use the preprocessor to insert that text in the middle of a string literal_" how can you do this? [I've tried](http://ideone.com/VSWsTz) without success.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster: I think he meant generate a string literal: http://ideone.com/akyOup. Once something is a string literal you cannot use the preprocessor to do anything to its syntactical structure, it's a single token.

Answer (score 1):

A `#define` tells the precompiler to replace all instances with the definition, so the type is not explicit in the variable, but it can be determined by looking at the literal value it represents.

- An integer literal is an `int` without any modifiers, or else can be made into a `long` etc. like 436234636L.
- A string literal is a normal string unless appended with modifiers as in your question.

Answer (score 1):

`#define` is a directive to the preprocessor, which just does copy-and-paste style replacements.  The preprocessor doesn't know or care anything about what the code means, and has no concept of types.

After preprocessing, the compiler deals with expressions, statements, types, and so on.  Every expression (unless it is the name or address of an overloaded function) has a type which only depends on that expression, not the context of code.

(C++11's *braced-init-lists* do not have types, and are not technically expressions although they can appear in many of the same contexts.)

So `#define VALUE 100` has meaning to the preprocessor, but at that point the idea of type doesn't even apply.  But almost any correct use of `VALUE` after that will use it as an expression, and those expressions will all have type `int`.

Yes, the number suffixes and string prefixes do affect the type of a literal expression.  The type of `100` is `int`, but the type of `100UL` is `unsigned long`.

The literal `"Text"` always has type `const char [5]`, but the exact meaning and representation of `char` can depend on your compiler.  In most contexts, that literal will instantly decay using the implicit array-to-pointer conversion, to the `const char*` type.  (Also, for backward compatibility with ancient C code from before the invention of `const`, C++ allows initializing a `char*` variable from a string literal, but it's better to not let that happen.)

Similarly, the literal `L"Text"` has type `const wchar_t [5]`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

When the preprocessor sees the text `#define VALUE 100`, it stores the string `VALUE` [or something like that], and the "replacement" as 100. Whenever the preprocessor later finds `VALUE`, it replaces it with `100`. As such, `VALUE` has no type. The text `100` in C does have a type - it is an `int`, because that's what the rules of the languages say.

Bear in mind that preprocessor replacement happens before the proper compilation, so preprocesor replacement can do all manner of "weird" things that is hard (or sometimes impossible) to do without macros.

Again, the preprocessor simply replaced `TEXT` with `"Text"` and at that point it has no type. Types only exist in the proper compiler. So if you have:

```
#define TEXT "Text"

void myfun(int x)
{
   ... 
}

... 
myfun(TEXT);
```

the preprocessor will produce

```
...
myfun("Text");
```

Only once you get to the proper compiling of the code will the compiler find that "Hmm, this is a text string, it's not an integer as expected", and give you some sort of error.

As to the "type" of `"Text"`, it does depend on the exact context. In most cases, the safe thing to do is treat it as `const char *`, but in some contexts, it can also be considered `char [5]`.